# word vba: looping through document resetting format

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

I want to loop through my word document removing all backgroundcolors on each word. This is my code so far but it is not working - I get the following error message "Argument not optional" and ".Item" is highlighted:

```
Sub ResetColor()
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set eword = doc.Range.Words.Item

 For i = 1 To doc.Range.Words

  eword.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
  eword.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
  eword.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic

 Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ResetColor()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For Each eword In doc.Range.Words

      eword.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
      eword.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
      eword.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error message "Command not available" and eword.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone is highlighted although the macro starts properly.

Comment: This error will occur if the document is protected or is read only.  Make sure you have write access to the document.

Comment: Hmm. No the document is not protected and not read only. Checked both but it worked on a new document so the macro works. Thx.